# Want to access custom object in apex class

Tags: apex, class

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Schema.Position at line 10 column
>   12

I am new to salesforce and following is my code :

```
public class c1{
    List <Position__c> pstn = new List<Position__c>();


    public List<Position__c> getpstn(){
    return pstn;
    }

    public PageReference ITReport_pstn(){
    pstn = [select Name, Type, Industry, Phone from Position where Type = 'IT Report'];
    return ITReports;
    }

    public PageReference NonITReport_pstn(){
    pstn = [select Name, Type, Industry, Phone from Position where Type = 'NonIT Report'];
    return NonITReports;
    }
```

[image]

this is the screenshot for custom field

Comment: I've edited your question for you this time to include your screenshot. For the future, you can edit your own questions (and answers) by clicking the "edit" link that sits right under the tags for your question. It doesn't really look like a link, but it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Position` is a custom object. The API name of custom object always end with `__c`. 
In your SOQL, you gave incorrect API name of the object, and therefore a compiler error was thrown

Updated code:

```
public class c1{
    List <Position__c> pstn = new List<Position__c>();

    public List<Position__c> getpstn(){
        return pstn;
    }

    public PageReference ITReport_pstn(){
        pstn = [select Name, Type, Industry, Phone from Position__c where Type = 'IT Report'];
        return ITReports;
    }

    public PageReference NonITReport_pstn(){
        pstn = [select Name, Type, Industry, Phone from Position__c where Type = 'NonIT Report'];
        return NonITReports;
    }
}
```

Refer [Custom object in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm)

Comment: ya i know that API name should always ends with__c but this time showing this error            Error: Compile Error:
select Name, Type, Industry, Phone from Position__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:14
No such column 'Type' on entity 'Position__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 9 column 16

Comment: The API names of custom field should also end with __c

Comment: Add a screenshot of the fields with the API name

Comment: FYI, for a custom object, most field names also end in `__c` e.g. `Type__c`. There is a lot of training material such as [Data Modeling](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_modeling) that you should go through to learn the basics, otherwise you will always be guessing as you work.

Comment: sent the screenshot please guide me now

Comment: As per the screenshot, append __c with `Type` and `Industry` and `Phone` are not the fields in Position object.

Comment: But ensure to give proper API name of the fields.

Comment: Please help me out...done the same as you said but again getting same error